# I didn't get requested page id url

Tags: php, url, get

```
function getUrl() {
  $url  = @( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != 'on' ) ? 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] :  'https://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
  $url .= ( $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] !== 80 ) ? ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : "";
  $url .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  return $url;
}
?>
```

if ($sessionUser == 1 || $sessionSeller == 1 || $sessionadmin == 1) { ?>
    
      
        :*
        
        
      
      " onClick="validate_form('frm_comment')" />
      " />
    
  
 " onClick="window.location.href='login.php?event=Account&url='"'" />

Still shows get url is like this : /login.php?event=Account&url=

how to get page like /login.php?event=Account&url=205 .....or anything

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
      $getUrl = $_GET['url']; 
      echo $getUrl;
?>
```